# ConfigurationManager.GetSection() returns null, how to fix this

Tags: .net, .net-core, config

Maybe this question is already answered, but I haven't seen anything that works for me.

The issue is the following: I can't read from app.config and I don't know what I am doing wrong, basically the idea is to get the object CcgSettingCcg which is of Type CcgSettings. In the future, I plan to add other settings, always CcgSettings but with different name, lets say CcgSettingsCcg2 and so on,

from app.config:

```
<configSections>
        <sectionGroup name ="GeneralTenantEmailSettings">
            <section name="TenantEmailSettings" type="DataApiService.Models.TenantEmailSettings, DataApiService.Models" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <TenantEmailSettings>
        <CcgSettingCcg SettingsId="520305DC-6E68-4FA3-B53B-18E25E0E21FF" TenantId="A0C55F11-516E-4F7C-9ECD-DEF7C47290B4" Frequency="168" StartDate="03/06/2020" RuleType="Default" To="Ccg" />
    </TenantEmailSettings>
```

Class definitions: I am using system.Configuration here

```
namespace DataApiService.Models{
public class CcgSettings : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("SettingsId", IsRequired=true)]
        public Guid SettingsId 
        {
            get
            {
                return (Guid)this["SettingsId"];
            }
            set
            {
                value = (Guid)this["SettingsId"];
            }
        }
        [ConfigurationProperty("TenantId", DefaultValue = null, IsRequired = false)]
        public Guid? TenantId
        {
            get
            {
                return (Guid)this["TenantId"];
            }
            set
            {
                value = (Guid)this["TenantId"];
            }
        }
        [ConfigurationProperty("Frequency", DefaultValue = 0,IsRequired = true)]
        public int Frequency
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)this["Frequency"];
            }
            set
            {
                value = (int)this["Frequency"];
            }
        }
        [ConfigurationProperty("StartDate", IsRequired = true)]
        public DateTime StartDate
        {
            get
            {
                return (DateTime)this["StartDate"];
            }
            set
            {
                value = (DateTime)this["StartDate"];
            }
        }
        [ConfigurationProperty("RuleType", DefaultValue = "default", IsRequired = true)]
        public string RuleType
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)this["RuleType"];
            }
            set
            {
                value = (string)this["RuleType"];
            }
        }
        [ConfigurationProperty("To", IsRequired = true)]
        public string To
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)this["To"];
            }
            set
            {
                value = (string)this["To"];
            }
        }
    }

    public class TenantEmailSettings: ConfigurationSection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("CcgSettings")]
        public CcgSettings CcgSettingsCcg
        {
            get
            {
                return (CcgSettings)this["CcgSettingCcg"];
            }
            set
            {
                value = (CcgSettings)this["CcgSettingCcg"];
            }
        }
    }
    public class GeneralTenantEmailSettings : ConfigurationSectionGroup
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("TenantEmailSettings")]

        public TenantEmailSettings TenantEmailSettings
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }}
```

and finally this is where I try to read

```
    var t = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("TenantEmailSettings") as TenantEmailSettings; 
    var s = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("GeneralTenantSettings") as GeneralTenantEmailSettings;
    var c = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("CcgSettings") as CcgSettings;
    var b = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("CcgSettingsCcg") as CcgSettings;
```

t, s, c and b return null, this is my problem

Comment: If you are using .net core you should use the new convention for configuration settings.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: thanks, but using a .config file instead of a json is part of the requirements

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: You might need to use a custom provider like this person did https://benfoster.io/blog/net-core-configuration-legacy-projects/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I had to use .NET core 2.2, I had issues with packages, and of course, context can't be inherited. Solution that I had was a bad one but it worked and meet the requirements.

The solution was to treat app.config as it was a general text file and parse from there. Something simple.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some sample code that should help, assuming you need to use app.config files. In order to make the example work you will need the following NuGet packages (v3.1.5 or newer)

- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Xml
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder

Example implementation

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.AddXmlFile("App.config");
var config = builder.Build();

var ccgSettingCcg = config.GetSection("TenantEmailSettings:CcgSettingCcg").Get<CcgSettingCcg>();

Console.WriteLine(ccgSettingCcg.SettingsId);
Console.WriteLine(ccgSettingCcg.TenantId);
Console.WriteLine(ccgSettingCcg.Frequency);
```

Example for `CcgSettingCcg.cs`

```
public class CcgSettingCcg
{
    public string SettingsId { get; set; }
    public string TenantId { get; set; }
    public int? Frequency { get; set; }

    // other properties as required
}
```

Example `App.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <TenantEmailSettings>
    <CcgSettingCcg SettingsId="520305DC-6E68-4FA3-B53B-18E25E0E21FF" TenantId="A0C55F11-516E-4F7C-9ECD-DEF7C47290B4" Frequency="168" StartDate="03/06/2020" RuleType="Default" To="Ccg" />
  </TenantEmailSettings>
</configuration>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I get an error but thanks, it has been an improvement. I'm getting System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException

Comment: @Iria you are using .NET Core, right? If so the above code should work (as that's how I tested it using a .NET Core 3.1 console app).

Comment: yes, I'm using .net core, the first part of the code is in program.cs, the second somewhere else

Comment: Perhaps you might be referencing the wrong configuration builder. When instantiating the builder try the fully qualified namespace `var builder = new Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder();`

Comment: I saw the issue, the nuget packages as I am using .net core 2.2 and those packages need 3.1 at least